# Cant signout of firebase in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, stream-builder

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_name/screens/auth_screen.dart';
import 'package:app_name/screens/catalog_screen.dart';
import 'package:app_name/screens/grid_screen.dart';
import 'package:app_name/screens/outstanding.dart';
import './screens/cart_screen.dart';
import './screens/dispatch_screen.dart';
import './screens/payment_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import './provider/selection_type.dart';
import './screens/catalog_screen.dart';
import './screens/selection.dart';
import './provider/cart_provider.dart';
import './provider/products_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static Map<int, Color> color = {
    50: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .1),
    100: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .2),
    200: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .3),
    300: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .4),
    400: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .5),
    500: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .6),
    600: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .7),
    700: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .8),
    800: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, .9),
    900: Color.fromRGBO(136, 14, 79, 1),
  };
  MaterialColor colorCustom = MaterialColor(0xFF415dc1, color);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Products(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: SelectionProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Cart(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: colorCustom, bottomAppBarColor: colorCustom),
        home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {
            if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
              return Selection();
            }
            return AuthScreen();
          },
        ),
        routes: {
          GridScreen.routeName: (ctx) => GridScreen(),
          CatelogScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CatelogScreen(),
          DispatchScreen.routeName: (ctx) => DispatchScreen(),
          PaymentsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => PaymentsScreen(),
          CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
          OutstandingScreen.routeName: (ctx) => OutstandingScreen(),
          AuthScreen.routeName: (ctx) => AuthScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AuthScreen.dart:

```
import 'dart:io';
import '../widgets/auth_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    static final routeName = '/auth_screen';

  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var isLoading = false;
  void _submitAuthForm(
    String email,
    String password,
    String userName,
    File image,
    bool isLogin,
    BuildContext ctx,
  ) async {
    AuthResult authResult;
    try {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      if (isLogin) {
        authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } else {
        authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );



        //files upload
        await Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(authResult.user.uid)
            .setData({
          'userName': userName,
          'email': email,
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      var message = 'An error occured';
      if (err.message != null) {
        message = err.message;
      }
      Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
      ));
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: AuthForm(_submitAuthForm, isLoading),
    );
  }
}
```

this makes the whole login,
after that the user login the selection page(seletion.dart) which then moves to the gridview.dart screen where i use 
`FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();` 
to signout but the gridscreen still appears on the screen,although the user is logged out the AuthScreen is not being shown ,
looks like the steamBuilder cannot listen to request change from 2nd child in the widget tree because if i logout in selection page(direct child) the user is logged out and the screen changes.
Please Help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `await` the `signOut` Event. I would also recommend you putting it into a `Future` .

It could look something like that:

```
Future handleSignOut() async {
  try {
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }catch (e){
    return (e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya but id still need to go a screen back to see the auth screen. I still need to add  `Navigator.pop(context);`   to the code.

Comment: Yeah do that after you have executed the Future